# Ordenar listview pela quantidade de likes no Firebase

Tags: android

Preciso que os itens do meu ListView com mais likes apareçam primeiro no meu feed, como faço isso?
segue imagem da estrutura do firebase[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Adapter

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View 
 convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View v = 
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);

    imgList = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("videos/");

    Query myTopPostsQuery = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("videos");



    myTopPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Fetch image data from firebase database
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : 
          dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                VideoUpload video = 
       snapshot.getValue(VideoUpload.class);
                string = video.getUrl();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de passar a lista para o adpter. Você pode ordenar-la usando como critérios a quantidade de likes. Esse exemplo mostra com implementar o Comparable, usado para ordenar um Objeto List.
Collections.sort(myLista), odena sua lista com os item com mais likes.

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>{
private String nome;
private int quantLike;

User(String nome, int idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.quantLike = idade;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public int getQuantLike() {
    return quantLike;
}

public void setQuantLike(int quantLike) {
    this.quantLike = quantLike;
}

 public int compareTo(User u) {
    if (getQuantLike() > u.getQuantLike()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (getQuantLike() < u.getQuantLike()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, mas obrigado pela ajuda